# Add hostname for each line in a text file using cmd

Tags: batch-file

I am new with the batch file.

How can I append hostname in a text file

-Text file 1 -

```
Text Line 0
Text Line 1
Text Line 2 
.
.
.
```

Expected result in Text File 2

```
Hostname + Text Line 0
Hostname + Text Line 1
Hostname + Text Line 2
. 
.
.
```

Comment: So basically you want to read a given file and append hostname in front of each line, right?

Comment: This is a straight code request, and therefore off topic here. Please research and write some code for us to help you fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
@echo off
echo %computername% + line 1 >>txtfilepath.txt
:: Continue like above, here %computername% is the host name
```